# How to know number of bytes AviMux Filter (or File Writer) has written into the file?

Tags: c++, winapi, directshow

After graph's stop, I want to know (programmatically) how many bytes it has written in the file. How to do it?

Comment: Use `FindFirstFile` to see how big the file on disk is.

Comment: When the graph is stopped the file is finalized. You should be able to check the completed file, specifically check its size. As a graph owner you should know the file name, or you can query it from the file writer.